# Bytebuddy doesn't work on zing

Tags: byte-buddy, azul-zing

Looks like bytebuddy doesn't work with zing jvm. Javaagent is initiated but interceptor is not activated. Anyone managed to get it to work with zing?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Looks like I jumped to conclusion too soon. It was another issue that gave us wrong impressions of bytebuddy not working. I can confirm that it works with zing too.

Answer (score 2):

For a short a while, Azul started offering a free trial of Zing and I was able to run Byte Buddy and all of its tests on their JDK. I can now confirm that Byte Buddy works on Zing without limitations, including the retransformation.

Comment: We've been using Byte Buddy with success for about 6 months now injecting into applications running on Zing. Thanks for the good work Rafael.